# Is there a name for functions with only one extremum?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, terminology

(Non-mathematician here)

Is there a general term for a function that has only one extremum?  That is, for example, a function for which there are no local minimums that are not also the global minimum?  The function in question is not necessarily differentiable at the extremum (for example, $ y=\mathopen|x\mathclose| $).

Comment: I don’t know if there’s a specific term for this. Convex and concave functions both have this property. Edit: If you define it on the whole real line, they have the property of having at most one extrema, though they might not have any.

Comment: It's tempting to suggest "bitonic" (by analogy with “monotonic”) but as far as I know that is not actually used.

Comment: @Eric The exponential function is convex  but has no extrema at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call such a function “unimodal” (by analogy to unimodal probability distributions).

NB this is not fully standard terminology (and I’m not aware of more standard terminology) so you’ll want to define the term for your readers.

Comment: In dynamical systems of the interval (i.e., maps from $[0,1]$ into itself), this is precisely the term used. The classical examples being the the [tent map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map) and the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). So the term does exist, but the context is possibly a bit narrow.